# Image upload filename problems

Tags: bug, uploading-images

StackExchange's image upload tool is very handy, and I especially like that you can just give it a url to get an image that's already on the internet. But there's a problem when trying to get png versions of svg images from Wikimedia Commons; it *appears*, though I can't say with confidence, that the image uploader complains that .svg.png is an unsupported file extension and rejects it for its filetype, despite supporting .png just fine (and the images are indeed plain png files).

I believe the standard practice for handling files with multiple extensions is to simply ignore all by the last, but it appears that isn't what's happening here.

Comment: This is probably a problem for meta.stackexchange.com instead of electronics.meta.stackexchange.com